# Recurrence relations with polynomial coefficients: an undecidable problem

Tags: recurrences, decidability

I read once (somewhere) that solving a recurrence relation with polynomial coefficients, in the general case, is an undecidable problem. I can't remember the exact reference and I've been trying to prove it myself for some time now. Is anyone familiar with a paper or proof of this?

Comment: It depends of what "solving" means. In Chapter 8 of the book "A = B", written by M. Petkovšek, H. S. Wilf, and D. Zeilberger, it is illustrate an algorithm to find if a recurrence with polynomial coefficient has a "closed form" in terms of hypergeometric functions or not.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for? 
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.0586v1.pdf

The issue here is of course the nesting of a function, which in general makes a mess out of everything (for example, Julia sets etc. where several undecidable questions exists)...

Answer (score 2):

Even computing the *asymptotics* of solutions of linear recurrence equations with polynomial coefficients is an open problem! From 
[[D.~Zeilberger,
AsyRec: A Maple package for computing the asymptotics of solutions of linear recurrence equations with polynomial coefficients,
*Personal Journal of Ekhad and Zeilberger* (4 April 2008), 2~pp.]](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/asy.pdf):

> I did not know much about computer algebra systems.  Now that I do, I
>   thought that it is about time to write a Maple implementation of the
>   Birkhoff--Trjitzinsky method so lucidly described in that paper.
>
> It is amazing how fast Maple, with the aid of this package, can
>   compute asymptotics of solutions of linear recurrence equations with
>   polynomial coefficients to *any* desired order.  In particular, it can
>   derive, very fast, the asymptotics for the number of involutions of
>   size $n$, that probably took Moser and Wyman (*Canadian J. Math.*
>   **7** (1955), 159--168) at least one month, and probably took Don Knuth (*The Art of Computing Programming*, vol. 3, 5.1.4) several
>   hours.
>
> Just type: "Asy(N**2-N-(n+1),n,N,10);", to get the asymptotics up to
>   the 10th order.
>
> The Birkhoff--Trjitzinsky method suffers from one drawback.  It only
>   does the asymptotics up to a multiplicative constant $C$.  But
>   **nowadays** this is hardly a problem. Just crank-out the first ten thousand  terms  of  the  sequence  using  the  very  recurrence 
>   whose  asymptotics  you  are  trying  to find, not forgetting to
>   furnish the few necessary *initial conditions*, and then
>   *estimate* the constant **empirically**.  If you are lucky, then Maple can recognize it in terms of "famous" constants like $e$ and $\pi$, by
>   typing "identify(C);"